# How to strip all the class (CSS) attributes in a HTML file in vscode?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I am creating email templates in HTML. I am using classes to style components during development. I want to strip all `class` attributes before shipping the final version. How to achieve it in VSCODE?

I tried selecting all occurances of the word `class`, but the length and number of the classes vary across the file. So this don't work.

```html
<tr>
  <td class="cta" height="32">
    <a class="cta-inner" href="#" style="color:#fff;"></a>
      Go To Task
    </a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I expect `cta` and `cta-inner` class to be removed from the resulting html.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

- Select class attribute and then press CTRL + F
- Type `class="[\w|\W]*?"` and press replace all
- Check the image below for more details

[image]

Comment: `class=".[^"]*"\s*`

Comment: You can improve it considering more tags' attributes apart from class with the following regex (in this case considering also `id`, `name`): `(class|id|name)="[\w|\W]*?"`